# How to add column one after another in pandas df using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am working with for loops. I will be doing some operations inside the loop. `The result would be an numpy array`. Now i just want to store the numpy array in pandas df for every for loop value.

**My df looks like below**

```
Lt        Lg
-7.0      -7.0
-7.0      -6.9
-7.0      -6.8
.         .
.         .
.         .
.         .
6.9       6.8       
6.9       6.9




df.shape is (19600,2)
```

**code example**

```
for i in range(21,25):
  ' do some operations and return below numpy array of length 19600'

  result_array = [0,0,0.2......0.8,0.6] # lenght of array = 19600

  df[i] = result_array
```

**result what i get**

```
Lt        Lg      24
-7.0      -7.0    0
-7.0      -6.9    0.2
-7.0      -6.8    0
.         .       .
.         .       .
.         .       .
.         .       .
6.9       6.8     0.8     
6.9       6.9     1
```

**Requirement**

```
Lt        Lg      21    22    23    24  
-7.0      -7.0    0     0     0     0
-7.0      -6.9    0.2   0     0.4   0.2
-7.0      -6.8    0     0.2   0.6   0
.         .       .     .     .     .
.         .       .     .     .     .
.         .       .     .     .     .  
.         .       .     .     .     .
6.9       6.8     0.8   0     0.6   0.8
6.9       6.9     1     0.4   0.2   1
```

It overwrites the column again and again and it produces the last calculated `result_array` merged with df.
But I required every `result_array` to be joined/merged with df.

Comment: what if you do `df.loc[:,i] = result_array ` ??

Comment: its produces same result as mentioned above...The column overwrites (Only column no 24 is shown)...@anky_91

Comment: cant reproduce, working fine for me. Check if you are assigning the df column under the for loop, check for indentations, etc..

Comment: Its working fine.

Comment: Please post actual code or a simulated one to reproduce your issues (i.e., [MCVE]).

Comment: I have some problem with the functions mentioned inside,where I am calling a class which runs once.Now I got better clarification..

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me normally..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Lt":[1,2,3,4],"Lg":[5,6,7,8]})

for i in range(21, 25):
    result_array = np.random.randint(0,10,4)  #Some function
    df[i] = result_array

df
```

[image]

The only thing that can cause this then is some error in your function that creates result_array. It seems that the function is not running properly. Can you elaborate on what is that function?

Comment: < 50 rep, i am new. don't be tilted.

Comment: I wasn't being tilted.  We collectively keep the site clean.

Comment: I understand, but technically this is the solution to the problem asked in the heading. This page should be for anyone asking for the solution that that problem. And, my comment diagnoses the only place of failure in the code, which is also a solution to the user posting the question. Please go through my history of answers, i dont spam, i dont put redundant information/solutions.

Comment: No hard feelings dude. I understand. :) Cheers..!!